# Where to use Auth->allow and Auth->deny in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.6, cakephp-3.6

I see that in the CakePHP 3 documentation examples the Auth component **allow** and **deny** functions are used in **initialize** function of the controllers. Whereas I see some examples online and on stackoverflow where people use those methods calls in **beforeFilter**.

What's the best and most efficient way to deal with this in CakePHP 3.6 application? Should I use the following method calls:

```
$this->Auth->allow(/*...*/);
$this->Auth->deny(/*...*/);
```

In **initialize** or **beforeFilter**?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Actual check if action is allowed is, by default, made in `Controller.startup` event. As defining allowed/disallowed actions needs to take place before that, and both `Controller::initialize()` and `Controller::beforeFilter()` meets this requirement, both should be good candidates to define allowed actions in.

But, in `Auth` config you can change event where this check is done, so a safer place for defining allowed actions would be `Controller::initialize()`, as it is called before any event that `Auth` can hook to.